# Julia equivalent to "not" in python

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia. I cannot find how to use a "not" operator as in python.
What I want to do: run a while loop as long as a function returns false.

In python I would do:

```
while not function(foo, bar):
    do_something
```

How would you achieve this effect in Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the standard `!`:

```
while !func(foo, bar)
    do_something
end
```

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for the pointer. I agree that information could have been added to the manual under flow control and/or boolean.  Only now I found out I could have found the information here https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.:! (albeit somewhat minimal)

Comment: Why are you putting a dot in front of the `!`? As far as I can tell there's no broadcasting happening here, or in fact it *cannot* happen because `while` only accepts a scalar boolean. Also remove the colon at the end of the line.

Comment: This is also listed on the [punctuation page](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/punctuation/#Punctuation)

Comment: @GhostGambler Please don't post blatantly wrong answers for a language that you don't know. (The answer is now correct due to the edit from Matt B.)